# Dispatch and Listen Action with Hooks in React (without Redux)

Tags: react.js

I wanted to share actions through different places in the component tree like:

```javascript
// in one component, listen an action
useListener("DELETE", (payload) => {
    console.log("DELETE EVENT 1", payload);
});

// in another component, dispatch action
const dispatch = useDispatch();
dispatch("DELETE", payload);
```

This is my implementation :

```javascript
const globalListener = {};

export const useListener = (actionName = "default", fn, dependencies = []) => {
    const listenerRef = useRef(Symbol("listener"));

    useEffect(() => {
        const listener = listenerRef.current;
        return () => {
            delete globalListener[actionName][listener];
        };
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const listener = listenerRef.current;
        if (!globalListener?.[actionName]) {
            globalListener[actionName] = {};
        }
        globalListener[actionName][listener] = fn;
    }, dependencies);
};

export const useAction = () => {
    const dispatch = (actionName, payload) => {
        const actionListener = globalListener?.[actionName];
        if (!actionListener) {
            return;
        }

        const keys = Reflect.ownKeys(actionListener);
        keys.forEach((key) => {
            actionListener[key]?.(payload);
        });
    };
    return dispatch;
};
```

I would like to hear what kind of risks/flaws this implementation can bring. I think I could use useReducer's middleware for such usage but it would be overkill to use the whole useReducer code to do such implementation.

What could be other approaches to solve this? With or without any extra library...